# Create undo and redo system in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, undo-redo

I hame building simple game in Unity3D where the user can place models in the scene, delete and move them.

I have built the basic part but now I want to add an undo-redo system. Undoing the movement is easy (just saving the previous position) but I am not sure how to undo/redo object's creation or deletion.

I am currently deleting it using the `Destroy` method and it is working as I want. But how can I had the option to undo it¿

I thought about disabling the GameObject and reactivate it when undoing but I am not sure it would be good for memory.

My game is targeted for low end PCs with only 4GB of ram and weak i3 processor.

Do you know a way to implement undo of object deletion¿

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." Disabling a gameObject have a lower overhead then destroying it anyway.

Comment: @Menyus But won't it be worse for memory¿

Comment: Ofcoure it will be but we are talking about KiloBytes here, there is no need to worry about it, i assume if your target device is such a low end pc, you are not going to spawn ten of thousands of gameObjects anyway

Comment: As Menyus said, Disable the GameObject with SetActive(). and if you want to redo you can just easily reactivate it. Otherwise, if there is loads of GameObjects you want to be able to turn on / off you could save them in a list/array and just loop thru that.

Comment: @Lunix46 The reason I prefer to destroy them, is because every models as something like 4 scripts on it. And if I don&#39;t destroy them the scripts and there variables would stay in memory.

Comment: Do they all have to have 4 scripts? Because im not sure if you actually can like undo a Delete(). There is something on the docs about this but I dont know if that will help. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate.html

Comment: @Lunix46 No, this function only works in editor…
I guess that I would try disable the GameObjects and check if there is a serious memory problems or not…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone mentioned in the comments, `Premature optimization is the root of all evil.`.

Use a simpler method first and see if it can work as intended without any issues.

If you have to, test out both, and use the [Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) to determine which suits you the best.

Also, a few good sources to read for you:

- https://www.quora.com/How-does-memory-work-in-Unity-Engine-Does-1-huge-cube-take-up-more-memory-space-or-many-smaller-cubes-totaling-the-same-volume-take-up-more-space-or-are-they-the-same?share=1
- https://answers.unity.com/questions/462942/does-inactive-objects-eat-up-performance.html
- https://answers.unity.com/questions/209101/do-un-active-game-objects-still-use-memory.html
- https://answers.unity.com/questions/783847/how-does-inactive-game-objects-affect-cpu-and-memo.html

*TLDR*; If you focus on optimizing memory usage, you might encounter performance issues. Vice versa.

### Undo-ing a Destroy() call

For undo-ing a `Destroy()` call, there is no simple solution for that.
What you can do is to store what kind of object you destroyed, and the information of the object before you destroyed.

For example, I have a bullet which has a few properties in it which I want it to persist after I Undo it's destruction.

**Bullet.cs**

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {

    public BulletInfo BulletInfo { get; private set; }

    private void Update() {
        // Fly, etc.
    }

    public void InitalizeBullet(BulletInfo bulletInfo) {
        BulletInfo = bulletInfo;
    }

    // ...

    public void DisposeBullet() {
        BulletUndoManager.Instance.AddDeletedBulletInfo(BulletInfo, transform.position);

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

**BulletInfo.cs**

```
public class BulletInfo {
    public float Speed { get; set; }
    public float Damage { get; set; }

    // Etc...
}
```

**BulletUndoManager.cs**

```
public class BulletUndoManager : MonoBehaviour {
    #region Singleton
    private static BulletUndoManager instance;

    public static BulletUndoManager Instance {
        get => instance;
    }
    #endregion

    private struct DeletedBulletInfo {
        public BulletInfo BulletInfo { get; private set; }
        public Vector3 LastPosition { get; private set; }
        public DeletedBulletInfo(BulletInfo bulletInfo, Vector3 lastPosition) {
            BulletInfo = bulletInfo;
            LastPosition = lastPosition;
        }
    }

    Stack<DeletedBulletInfo> lastDeletedBullet;

    [SerializeField, Tooltip("The prefab of the bullet")]
    private Bullet bulletPrefab;

    private void Awake() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void UndoBulletDeletion() {
        if (lastDeletedBullet.Count > 0) {
            DeletedBulletInfo lastDeletedBulletInfo = lastDeletedBullet.Pop();

            var newBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab);

            newBullet.InitalizeBullet(lastDeletedBulletInfo.BulletInfo);
            newBullet.transform.position = lastDeletedBulletInfo.LastPosition;
        }
    }

    public void AddDeletedBulletInfo(BulletInfo bulletInfo, Vector3 bulletLastPosition) {
        lastDeletedBullet.Push(new DeletedBulletInfo(bulletInfo, bulletLastPosition));
    }
}
```

Notice that the concept is roughly the same as undo-ing or redo-ing a movement of an object.

The only major difference is this:

- I store something else other than position. (Mainly information before destruction)
- I pass the all the data that was stored to the newly created object. (Created upon undo-ing a `Destroy()`)

*The only real difficulty here is how you are going to store the information, and how you are going to pass it into the newly created object.*

Comment: Got it, so basically my options are disabling the object or saving the important data and then destroying it. I am still reading the links you added, Thank you very much